# Getting diagonals of this matrix

Tags: python, search, cpu-word, diagonal

I am trying to create a function that would get the diagonal from a list within a list a.k.a matrix of my word search puzzle.

```
def get_left_up (start_x, start_y, board):
word = []
for row in range (start_x, -1,-1):
    for col in range (start_y,-1, -1):
        word.append(board[row][col])
word = ''.join(word)
return word

get_left_down (start_x, start_y, board):
word = []
for row in range (start_x,len(board)):
    for col in range (start_y,-1,-1):
        word.append(board[row][col])
word = ''.join(word)
return word

def get_right_up (start_x, start_y, board):
word= []
for row in range (start_x,-1,-1):
    for col in range (start_y,len(board)):
        word.append(board[row][col])
word = ''.join(word)
return word

def get_right_down (start_x, start_y, board):
word = []
for row in range (start_x, len(board)):
    for col in range (start_y,len(board)):
      word.append(board[row][col])
word = ''.join(word)
return word
```

as of now, those where the functions that I should work on. However, something's wrong. I intend to put in arguments of the coordinates of the first letter matched from the word being searched to the board and concatenate the characters from each direction of the diagonals.

Comment: You should have only one loop in which you update the col and row number at the same time, not two imbricated loops. You could use a `while` loop, testing that you stay on the board.

Answer (score 0):

For the right down diagonal, you need to increase x- and y- in the same iteration, and not loop over all column entries for a specific row.

```
def get_right_down (start_x, start_y, board):
   word = []
   col = start_y
   for row in range (start_x, len(board)):
      if col >= len(board):
         break
      word.append(board[row][col])
      col = col + 1
   return ''.join(word)
```